# Extracting useful data from ArcGIS Pro results output xml

Tags: arcgis-pro, xml, batch, output

I have a very large iterative operation in ArcGIS Pro that takes days, or weeks to complete.

I have to run it on 20 regional datasets for England and Wales. For a small dataset, like Bedfordshire, it completes successfully in two hours.

But for a large dataset, like Outer London, it starts quickly, but progressively slows, even to a point where every additional hour it runs pushes the projected time of completion into the future by more than an hour - so it could run infinitely.

I have stopped processing the Outer London dataset after six days after it passed that point.

I am waiting for Pro to settle down so that I can examine the XML log. But the output is very verbose, and practically useless in this format. What I want to do is to extract the timings of the various operations from the output window (example from the log here).

> Executing (Iterate Feature Selection): IterateFeatureSelection
> D:\ArcGIS\Pro\Projects\ED81_to_Coast98\Working.gdb\Where__in_Census_Tracts__EDs_DID_change_by_time_of_1981_Census
> "TRACT #" false Start Time: 17 January 2022 06:35:16 Succeeded at 17
> January 2022 06:35:17 (Elapsed Time: 0.41 seconds)

So, I'd a CSV file with:

| AreaCode | Iterate_Feature_Selection | Next_Function |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxxxx | Elapsed Time | Elapsed Time |
| xxxxxxy | Elapsed Time | Elapsed Time |
| xxxxxxz | Elapsed Time | Elapsed Time |

I'd then be able to analyse the timings and determine an optimal standard batch size (to replace my current 20).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your question:  How do I parse an XML log file?

Comment: Just as a note - from the (ArcMap) help:  Logging can affect tool performance, especially in models that use iterators. For example, you may have a model that runs the Append tool thousands of times, appending features to the same feature class. If logging is enabled, each iteration in the model updates the metadata of the feature class, which slows down the performance of the model.

Comment: Alex has some good information here (although for ArcMap, I suspect it'd be valid for Pro). https://tereshenkov.wordpress.com/2016/05/09/geoprocessing-history-logging-in-arcgis-performance-review/  -- Basically turn logging off unless you're 100% certain this is not causing a performance problem and you understand that by creating these diagnostic logs, they could be making your problem worse.

Comment: Hey @KHibma, interesting question this, for ArcPro do you know where logs from a model run are stored?

Comment: @Hornbydd I see logs from Models at `%AppData%\Esri\ArcGISPro\ArcToolbox\History`

Comment: Thank you for your input, @KHibma. Once I cancelled Outer London and ArcGIS Pro settled down to allow me access to the log, I was able to examine the timings for each operation on each census tract. Over the course of the 108 hours it ran, the total processing time for each cycle rose from about 15 seconds to over 180.  While this was significant, it only accounted for a total of 30 hours' processing.  Much of the rest can be put down to saving intermediate outputs to disk (now changed to 'in_memory'. I will now disable the log and see how much that speeds things up too.  Thanks again.

Comment: @BruceMitchell Oh ya, there's absolutely ways to optimize your GP tools, `memory` is right near the top of the "fixes". Per your question now, if you have a solution maybe you could self answer?